# Disposing Samples c#

Tags: c#, idisposable

Looking at the sample code of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
// Design pattern for a base class.
public class Base: IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    //Implement IDisposable.
    public void Dispose()
    {
          Dispose(true);      <---- 1 Here
          GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
         if (!disposed)
         {
             if (disposing)
             {
                 // Free other state (managed objects).
             }
             // Free your own state (unmanaged objects).
             // Set large fields to null.
             disposed = true;
         }
    }

   // Use C# destructor syntax for finalization code.
   ~Base()
   {
       // Simply call Dispose(false).
       Dispose (false);
   }
}
```

I don't seem to get the line of code pointed in the first arrow (<----- 1 Here).

I was confused in the first arrow as to Whom the Dispose belong. to the IDisposable or the virtual Dispose of the base?

Any Help that would help me is Great and Very much appreciated!

Comment: Here is an explanation for proper way to implement IDisposable http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P. Let me know if this makes it clear

Comment: This pattern is used to avoid multiple invocations of the user's code in the disposer. The Dispose(false) is called every time Garbage Collector decides to destroy the object, and you can't control when that happens. the Dispose(true) is called every time the object is disposed in your code (or from the library) either from using(){} finalizer, or from explicit calls to Dispose() method. As you can see, the Dispose() method is final and you can't override it, but the Dispose(boolean) method is virtual, so you can use it to clean up your state in the class inherited from Base

Comment: not sure what you're confused at?

Comment: Thanks @SureshKumarVeluswamy! I'll read it ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, the Dispose belongs to the caller aka dev.

```
public void Dispose()
{
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

This is never automatically called, but always by the developer. The `true` flag indicates that the dispose was explicitly called. `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` tells the Garbage Collector that the disposal of that object is already taken care of. No need to call the finalize block.

---

```
~Base()
{
    // Simply call Dispose(false).
    Dispose (false);
}
```

This is automatically called by the Garbage Collector if the object has not been explicitly disposed. It is undetermined when exactly it is called, but sometime when the object has gone out of scope and is marked to be garbage collected. The `false` flag indicates that this is an automatic disposal in which case managed objects no longer need to be explicitly disposed.

Also, an additional note about finalizers taken from Ben Watson's Writing High-Performance .NET Code

> Never implement a finalizer unless it is required. Finalizers are code, triggered by the garbage
>   collector to cleanup unmanaged resources. They are called from a single thread, one after the
>   other, and only after the garbage collector declares the object dead after a collection. This
>   means that if your class implements a finalizer, you are guaranteeing that it will stay in memory
>   even after the collection that should have killed it. This decreases overall GC efficiency and
>   ensures that your program will dedicate CPU resources to cleaning up your object.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of the `Dispose(true)` / `Dispose(false)` is so that the *real* code - the `virtual void Dispose(bool)` - knows whether it is being called via dispose or finalize. The `Dispose(bool)` is specific to the class (the virtual  method); `IDisposable` only has a parameterless `Dispose()` method. As  such:

- the `Dispose(true)` route will only be called via `IDisposable` - which typically means via `using`
- the `Dispose(false)` route will only be called via the garbage collector

(note that the `Dispose(true)` route *disables* the finalization step once complete)

This boolean flag is important, because during finalization you can't touch *any* other managed resources (because order is non-deterministic) - only unmanaged. The fact that this method is `virtual` means that subclasses can add their own cleanup code into the mix.

In reality, though, it is **very** rare that you need to implement a finalizer; you should not add this much boilerplate routinely.

Comment: Marc — I think ( I might be wrong ) that he asks if he has class `Person` which inherits `Base` and it has it's own disposable  - so which methods are being called...

Comment: If that is the case, OP has misunderstood the example, in which they show how you could override the base class's dispose behavior by using an override.

Comment: @TimothyGroote since the only method `Dispose` which accepts bool is the virtual one , so there is no where to go wrong. Also OP wrote : _to the IDisposable or the virtual Dispose of the base_. It can't be to the Idisposeable since it doesnt has bool arg. so my understanding( again - i might be wrong) that he talks about another inheritance.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thanks! I got grinded up by the code that I forget Dispose(true) has an arg of bool.  Also, the interface inheritance(of its methods) got me confused that I didn't get it the first time. :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks! so is the Destructor = Finalizer? Thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: @Reyn the terminology is kinda used loosely / interchangeably, so essentially: yes

Answer (score 0):

This implementation:

```
public void Dispose(){...}
```

is for using others from this class's Dispose method. and this implementation:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){...}
```

is for using class itself means if others use `Dispose()` on their code, then can do something else that managed on protected method, but if garbage collector dispose it, it wouldn't run managed code